# running bash commands from windows command prompt working intermittently

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I'm trying to run a linux executable from the windows system through bash, but am having intermittent problems. I've narrowed it down to the fact that bash itself seems to sometimes run and sometimes not when I invoke it from windows. For example, a very simple command such as below will sometimes work correctly:

```
C:\>bash -c "pwd"
/mnt/c

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

and sometimes it will give no output and return a status of 1:

```
C:\>bash -c "pwd"

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

I would appreciate any hints for how I might trouble-shoot this issue. I've verified that when I open an Ubuntu terminal the same command works correctly 100% of the time, whereas from the Windows command line the success rate is roughly 50%.

Comment: What if you replace it with `wsl pwd` instead?  The `bash` executable is [deprecated for WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#deprecated-wsl-commands), but I've never seen this type of issue before.  Also worth trying `wsl -e pwd` and `wsl -e bash -lic pwd`.

Comment: Thanks @NotTheDro1ds. I tried your suggestion of using `wsl` instead of `bash`, but unfortunately it gives the same behavior: sometimes it works and sometimes it returns status 1.

Comment: After a machine reboot this problem now has gone away and I can no longer reproduce it. Will update if it comes back.

Comment: Correction: the problem is still there after the reboot, just happening less frequently. It is now failing about 1% of the time.

Comment: Is it still happening when you start from `C:\` as in the example in the question?  I'm assuming so, just want to confirm.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds yes, I've been testing from C: to try and eliminate as many variables as possible. I also tried from Cmd window and PowerShell window with same result. Currently it has stopped failing again, but I anticipate the problem will probably return.

Comment: I just noticed something.  Previously, calling `wsl -e not_a_command` (or most "error" conditions) would react the same as what you are seeing - No error message, but a non-zero exit status.  But, since you have Windows 11, you can install the "Windows Subsystem for Linux Preview" from the Microsoft Store.  What I notice is that it now provides some additional error messages and context when something like this happens.  It might be useful to install so that the next time you see this happen, you get more output that might be helpful.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thanks for the suggestion. The Preview is what I have installed and indeed it gives some error info in your example as follows:  `<3>init: (29998) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:528: execvpe not_a_command failed 2
<3>init: (29998) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:538: Create process not expected to return` but unfortunately it stays silent when it fails on a legitimate command such as `pwd`.